# R - Dropped rows

Tags: r, rows

I have a dataset which gives the  number of relatives who help a senior in his everyday life. I have an other part of the survey focusing on the senior.

Some seniors are not helped at all by relatives, so my first dataset has less rows than the second.

I would like to count the number of hours given by relative to each senior (a senior can be helped by numerous relatives), and for every senior who is not helped, NA should be displayed.

Rows go from 1 to 10628.

Here is my first dataset:

```
head(relative)
id_senior    id_relative    hours_care
  1              1             3
  1              2             6
  3              1             5
  3              2             0
  3              3             1
  4              1             3
  ...
 10628          1             34
```

Here is my second one :

```
head(senior)

id_senior 
   1
   2
   3
   4
  ...
 10628
```

And I would like something like this:

```
head(senior) #or whatever the name
id_senior    nbr_relative      sum_hours
  1            2                  9
  2            0                  NA  
  3            3                  6
  4            1                  3
 ...
 10638         1                  34
```

I tried something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

#To count the number of relatives
nbr_relatives <- relatives %>% 
  group_by(id_senior = factor(id_senior, levels = min(id_senior):max(id_senior)), .drop = FALSE) %>%
  summarise(relatives = n_distinct(id_relatives))

#The value 0 is given to every relatives which has no care hours value
subset_caregivers$hours_recoded[is.na(subset_caregivers$hours_recoded)] <- 0


nbr_relatives <-  relative %>% 
  group_by(id_senior = factor(id_senior, levels = min(id_senior):max(id_senior))) %>%
  count(hours = sum(hours_care), na.rm = TRUE)
```

But the number of rows in the dataset nbr_relatives become 4564, the number of senior helped, not 10628!

Where am I mistaken?

Comment: Does it work if you add `.drop = FALSE` to your second `group_by()`?

Comment: I have this error message:   Problem with `mutate()` input `idmen_care`.
x argument inutilisé (.drop = FALSE)
i Input `idmen_care` is `factor(...)`. //// "argument inutilisé" means "unused argument" in French

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Base-R,

```
merge(senior, aggregate(hours_care ~ id_senior, relative, sum), by = "id_senior", all.x=T)

   id_senior hours_care
1          1          9
2          2         NA
3          3          6
4          4          3
5          5         NA
         ...
20        20         NA
```

---

Edit:

to get the extra column in

```
    merge(senior, merge(aggregate(id_relative ~ id_senior, relative, length),aggregate(hours_care ~ id_senior, relative, sum)), by = "id_senior", all.x=T)

   id_senior id_relative hours_care
1          1           2          9
2          2          NA         NA
3          3           3          6
4          4           1          3
5          5          NA         NA
6          6          NA         NA
              ...
```

---

Data:

```
relative <- structure(list(id_senior = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L), id_relative = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), hours_care = c(3L, 6L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

senior <- data.frame(id_senior = 1:20)
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!